# Error Installing QuantLib-Python Quantitative Finance Library in Windows 7 x64

Tags: boost, windows-7-x64, quantlib

While building quantlib on Windows x64 I am receiving the following errors:

```
"D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\QuantLib_vc14.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(PostBuildEvent target) ->
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLogLinearDiscountConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLinearDiscountConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLinearZeroConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testSplineZeroConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLinearForwardConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testFlatForwardConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testConvexMonotoneForwardConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]      
    unknown location : fatal error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLocalBootstrapConsistency)": class QuantLib::Error: time (0.483333) is past max curve time (0.472222) [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error SB3073: The command ""D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\bin\QuantLib-test-suite-vc140-x64-mt.exe" --log_level=message --build_info=yes --result_code=no --report_level=short\r [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1. [D:\local\QuantLib-1.9.1\test-suite\testsuite.vcxproj]
```

Is there a known fix for this?

Compile commands:

```
set myboost=C:\local\boost_1_63_0
set INCLUDE=%myboost%;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=%myboost%\lib64-msvc-14.0;%LIB%
set UseEnv=true

msbuild /p:AdditionalLibPaths="%myboost\lib" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 QuantLib_vc14.sln
```

Comment: It looks like it has built but the post build step, running the tests fails.

Comment: That's correct.  The library was built, but there are errors in the test suite. It's a known issue that surfaced recently (see <https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/189>).  You can ignore the errors and continue building the Python wrappers, if that was your intent.

Comment: @Luigi Yes, and everything thereafter worked as expected.